# Move files in C#

Tags: c#, file, move

I am moving some images (filenames are`(1).PNG`, `(2).PNG` and so on) from one directory to another. I am using the following code:

```cs
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    try
    {
        from = "E:\\vid\\(" + i + ").PNG";
        to = "E:\\ConvertedFiles\\" + i + ".png";
        File.Move(from, to); // Try to move
        Console.WriteLine("Moved"); // Success
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex); // Write error
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

A first chance exception of type `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` occurred in mscorlib.dll

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'E:\vid\(1).PNG'.
```

Also, I am planning to rename the files so that the converted file name will be `00001.png`, `00002.png`, ... `00101.png` and so on.

Comment: Silly question, but you're sure that "E:\vid(1).PNG" exists?

Comment: `Could not find file 'E:\vid(1).PNG'` but your code says `E:\\vid\\(1).png` - so there's a slash missing here somewhere, no?

Comment: Something is wrong: your code expects the files to be named `(_num_).png` and reside in the `E:\vid` directory. The error messages states that you were trying to "find" the file `vid(_num_).png` in the `E:\\` directory. So error message and code don't match. Please make sure you posted the actual code and error message that match.

Comment: Something wrong in your code above? the file you are trying to move is named `(1).png` inside the folder `E:\vid`, not `E:\vid(1).png`. Which is the right one?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suggest you to use `'@'` in order to escape slashes in a more readable way. Use also `Path.Combine(...)` in order to concatenate paths and `PadLeft` in order to have your filenames as your specifics.

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    try
    {
        from = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"E:\vid\","(" + i.ToString() + ").PNG");
        to = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"E:\ConvertedFiles\",i.ToString().PadLeft(6,'0') + ".png");

        File.Move(from, to); // Try to move
        Console.WriteLine("Moved"); // Success
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex); // Write error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use something like this?

```
var folder = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\vid\"));

if (folder.Exists)
{
    var files = folder.GetFiles(".png");
    files.toList().ForEach(f=>File.Move(from,to));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception means that the file `E:\vid(1).PNG` doesn't exist. Do you mean `E:\vid1.PNG`?

Use `System.IO.Path` class for constructing paths, it's better than concatenating strings. You don't have to worry about escapting backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
i.ToString()
```

might help you. You are passing

```
from = "E:\\vid\\(" + i + ").PNG";
to = "E:\\ConvertedFiles\\" + i + ".png";
```

I as integer and concatenation doesn't work due to that
and instead of using `\\`, add `@` like this

```
from = @"E:\vid\(" + i + ").PNG";
```

Comment: `ToString()` is called implicitly when contcatenating with a string. If this was the problem, his code wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this in Visual Studio.  It worked.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication2

{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int n = 3;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                string from = "C:\\vid\\(" + i + ").PNG";
                string to = "C:\\ConvertedFiles\\" + i + ".png";
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Move(from, to); // Try to move
                        Console.WriteLine("Moved"); // Success
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e); // Write error
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Maybe when you were moving files into vid directory to begin the test, windows shaved off the parenthesis.  (1).png became 1.png... I got a file not found error from that phenomenon... otherwise, your code is solid.  My version is almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
var folder = new DirectoryInfo(sourcefolder);

if (folder.Exists)
{
    var files = folder.GetFiles("*.png");
    files.ToList().ForEach(f => File.Move(sourcefolder + f, newFolderName + f));
}
```

I believe this will help.